# C++ Named Pipe WriteFileEx / ReadFile, unicode / ansi

Tags: c++, windows, file-io, pipe

I am trying to pass data from an x64 app to a x86 app using named pipes and overlapped I/O like what is defined here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365603(v=vs.85).aspx

My server application's call to WriteFileEx succeeds and the structure I am sending through the pipe seems ok, however when I call ReadFile on the client side the data structure I retrieve is corrupted or different to the data that I sent, but it also successfully reads.

My client application has a unicode character set and the server's character set is 'not set', which I assume defaults to multibyte. I'm not in a position to change the server's character set to unicode.

Would this data corruption just be because I need to convert from multibyte to wide char on the client after I retrieve / read the data structure? If so is there built in helper functions that I can call on do to that?

Data structure being sent (defined identically on the server and client):

```
typedef struct
{
    int id;
    float vertices[VERTICES_COUNT][VERTICES_COMPONENTS];
    unsigned short indices[INDICES_COUNT];
    float texCoords[TEXTURE_COORD_COUNT][TEXTURE_COORD_COMPONENT];
    unsigned char texData[TEXTURE_SIZE];
} MESHINST, *LPMESHINST;

typedef struct
{
    OVERLAPPED oOverlap;
    HANDLE pipeInst;
    int addedCount;
    MESHINST meshes[MESH_GROUP_BUFFER];
    int removedCount;
    int removed[MESH_REMOVE_BUFFER];

} MESHGROUPINST, *LPMESHGROUPINST;
```

WriteFileEx call on the server:

```
LPMESHGROUPINST meshes = (LPMESHGROUPINST)lpOverLap;
fWrite = WriteFileEx(
    meshes->pipeInst,
    (wchar_t*)meshes,
    sizeof(MESHGROUPINST),
    (LPOVERLAPPED)meshes,
    (LPOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE)CompletedWriteRoutine);
```

ReadFile call on the client:

(in header)

```
MESHGROUPINST _meshes;
```

(in cpp)

```
do
{
    _success = ReadFile(
        _pipe,
        (wchar_t*)&_meshes,
        sizeof(MESHGROUPINST),
        &_numOfBytesRead,
        NULL);
} while (!_success);
```

Comment: Traditionally you would want to pass a void pointer as the buffer.  If you can't guarantee that the structure is byte for byte identical on the client and server you're going to need to serialise/deserialise it properly.

Comment: `ReadFile`/`WriteFileEx` are not affected by Unicode settings. The problem is elsewhere. It's not clear why you're casting to `wchar_t*` either, because both of those take `void*`.

Comment: The issue isn't Unicode/ANSI. The issue is 64-bit/32-bit. Your structure includes an `OVERLAPPED` structure and a `HANDLE`, both of which change size between 64-bit and 32-bit, and which @CoryNelson notes [don't make sense to transfer between processes anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25418647/902497).

Comment: I will factor these out of the structure that actually gets written / sent (I'll test it when I get home), and then I'll see how it goes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the type of `_meshes` in the `ReadFile` call? If it's a pointer, you'll be reading into the pointer, not the data being pointed to:

```
&_meshes
```

Should be:

```
_meshes
```

Also, it looks like you're writing process-specific `HANDLE` and `OVERLAPPED` info. Did you mean to write those?

You'll need to add more code for better help.

Comment: Sending the HANDLE and OVERLAPPED data in the structure ended up being the reason I got misaligned data on the client side I believe, because after removing it from being sent it just works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the structure is sent and received with 1-byte packing. Use `#pragma pack(1)` around the struct you wish to send/receive:

```
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct
{
    int id;
    float vertices[VERTICES_COUNT][VERTICES_COMPONENTS];
    unsigned short indices[INDICES_COUNT];
    float texCoords[TEXTURE_COORD_COUNT][TEXTURE_COORD_COMPONENT];
    unsigned char texData[TEXTURE_SIZE];
} MESHINST, *LPMESHINST;
#pragma pack()
```

Comment: This struct will pack identically on x86 and x64. No need to do this.